# Variable does not exist: User.statecode when deploying Apex class

Tags: apex, deployment

I use the following code in order to retrieve the list of configured states in the org.

```
private static List<String> getStateList()
{
    List<String> stateList = new List<String>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = User.statecode.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();        
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
        stateList.add(f.getLabel());
    }
    
    
    return stateList;
}
```

However, when trying to deploy the code, I run into the following error: Variable does not exist: User.statecode

Can anyone shed some light on this issue - I am unable to deploy without this error being fixed.

Comment: Is State Country Picklist enabled?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. Thank you for including the actual error. But please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/347192/edit) your question to also include where you are attempting to deploy the code (e.g., scratch org, sandbox, Production). It could make a difference to the specifics of an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StateCode` field is available for org if country picklist is enabled in the org.

Make sure, that you have it enabled for your environment.

in lightning:

Setup ->  Data ->  State and Country/Territory Picklists -> Complete all the steps

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I had thought that I already turned it on in the target org but this has solved my issue :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to build an [Unlocked Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_intro.htm), you need to specify this feature in your [Scratch Org Definition File](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm).

Example definition file:

```
{ "edition": "Enterprise", 
  "features": ["StateAndCountryPicklist"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't but this is good to know for the future :)

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000338321&type=1&mode=1) you need to first:

> Makes sure the state and country picklist is enabled in the ORG

This is likely the problem.